# How to connect a linux device to WiFi using WPS?

Tags: c, linux, networking, wifi

I am trying to bring up a network device. It required to be connected to a Wifi Network. But since the device doesn't have any keyboard I was planning to use WPS for connecting to a network. My device runs Linux based os. I don't have any clue in implementing the WPS feature. Is there any linux library present? Please guide me to a good starting point. I prefer C library for this since I don't have a JVM running in the device.

Answer (score 0):

the router is suposed to have wps button. when u connect with wps throught your device it will search for open wps point (for mobile) or for PC you have to sellect network and try connect, there should pop up a window saying you can also connet with wps . at that time you press the button on a router

Comment: I am looking for its implementation.